# Problem on Natural numbers and perfect squares

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, sums-of-squares

What is the smallest natural number to be added to the natural number $n$ to make it a perfect square?

Comment: Does this suffice? A smallest natural number that we are after is $m=\lceil\sqrt{n}\rceil^2−n$.

Comment: Looks correct to me.

Comment: That's actually a pretty good way of putting it.  Without knowing more about $n$ there really isn't anything specific we can say except, we know there *is* a specific answer and it is whatever it happens to be.  There is a unique whole number so that $m^2 \le n < (m+1)^2$  or in other words so that $m \le \sqrt{n} < m$.  We can reference $m$ as $[\sqrt{n}]$.  Hence we want $([\sqrt{n}] + 1)^2 - n$. ... oh, if $m > 0$ you must adjust your answer.... very minorly.